# How to sort data on php laravel before exporting them on .csv?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

I am trying to sort the datas before exporting them on excel. This is the code that I have been using:

```
public function getDashboardReport2(){
    (...)
        echo "<tr><td>Group Name</td><td>Unit</td><td>Unit Number</td><td>First Name</td><td>Last Name</td><td>Phone Number</td></tr>";

        ($group = \App\Group::find($auth_event->group_id);
                $bookings = \App\EventBookings::where("group_id", "=", $auth_event->group_id)->get();
                if($bookings->count() > 0){
                    foreach ($bookings as $booking){

                        $egroup = \App\EventGroup::find($booking->eg_id); // Here I tried orderBy('name');
                        $chalet = \App\Chalet::find($booking->chalet_id);
                            if($egroup) {
                            $egroup_members = \App\EventGroupMembers::where("eg_id", "=", $egroup->eg_id)->get();
                            $row = 0;
                                if ($egroup_members->count() > 0) {
                                    foreach ($egroup_members as $egroup_member) {
                                    $row++;
                                    $user = \App\User::find($egroup_member->user_id);
                                        if ($user) {
                                        $charges = \App\EventBookingCharges::where("user_id", "=", $user->user_id)
                                        ->where("booking_id", "=", $booking->booking_id)->get();
                                        $paid_amount = 0;
                                        $balance_amount = 0;
                                            if ($charges->count() > 0) {
                                                foreach ($charges as $charge) {
                                                    if ($charge->status == 1) {
                                                        $paid_amount = $paid_amount + $charge->amount;
                                                    } else {
                                                        $balance_amount = $balance_amount + $charge->amount;
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            })
                                echo "<tr>";

                                    if ($row == 1) {
                                    echo "<td>" . $egroup->name . "</td>"; // Sort using this data
                                    } else {
                                    echo "<td></td>";
                                    }

                                    if ($row == 1) {
                                    echo "<td>" . ($chalet ? $chalet->name : '') . "</td>";
                                    } else {
                                    echo "<td></td>";
                                    }

                                echo "</tr>";
                                }
                            }
                        echo "<tr><td colspan='9'><br></td></tr>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
```

How do I sort this one out? I have tried `orderBy('name');` but it didn't work. I also tried searching it on google but all the tutorials are about sorting arrays.

Comment: Going to need more context and code. Where is `$row` coming from?  Where did you try the `orderBy`? Are the results coming from a database?

Details, man! Details!

Comment: Sorry @ChrisSprague, sir. I updated the question please check. Thank you for your reply

Comment: 1. You seem to have many things you could sort here. so what is it that you want to sort? 2. this looks like laravel. maybe you should mention that since there are sorting possibilities that plain php does not have

Comment: @Cashbee I only need to sort this by group name `$egroup->name`. Thank you for your reply

Comment: this confuses me, since \App\EventGroup::find($booking->eg_id); returns only 1 EventGroup and you cant sort 1 thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i understand now what you want to order. you want to order the bookings according to their egroups name!

Im afraid I dont see an immediate answer for that unless you saved not only the eg_id in the bookings table but also the eg_name. then you could do something like

```
$bookings = \App\EventBookings::where("group_id", "=", $auth_event->group_id)->orderBy('eg_name')->get();
```

sorry for not being able to provide a better answer but i hope i could still be of help

Comment: Inside the `EventBookings` is only the `eg_id` that is connecting them ($egroup). Thank you for your reply. I appreciate it